# Set Image Wallpaper Intent in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-intent, wallpaper

Hi i have tried different ways to set my downloaded images from server as wallpaper using the native android intent in flutter but so far i am unable to implement it.
I have tried the intent package from pub.dev flutter but this code doesn't make my image pass through intent.

```
   android_intent. Intent()
    ..setAction(android_action.Action.ATTACH_DATA)
    ..setData(outputFileUri)
    //..putExtra(Extra.EXTRA_STREAM, outputFileUri)
    ..addFlag(1)
    ..setType('image/*')
    ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Anyway to fix this would be really helpful. I am also sharing the functionality i want like in the image
[t,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXZFW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your situation:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
```

It's also independent of the image data type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but i want to do this in flutter not android. I need flutter code